# python equivalent of get() in R (= use string to retrieve value of symbol)

Tags: python, r

In R, the `get(s)` function retrieves the value of the symbol whose name is stored in the character variable (vector) `s`, e.g.

```
X <- 10
r <- "XVI"
s <- substr(r,1,1) ## "X"
get(s)             ## 10
```

takes the first symbol of the Roman numeral `r` and translates it to its integer equivalent.

Despite spending a while poking through R-Python dictionaries and Googling various combinations of "metaprogramming", "programming on the language", "symbol", "string", etc., I haven't come up with anything.  (I am a very experienced R user and a novice Python user.)

(I know the example above is a (very!) poor way to approach the problem.  I'm interested in the general answer to this question, not specifically in converting Roman numerals to integers ...)

Comment: Just so you know, if you were going to do conversion of Roman numerals, you'd probably be best off having a dictionary `r={'M':1000,'D':500,'C':100,'L':50,'X':10,'V':5,'I':1}`, and just using `r['X']`.

Comment: yes, I did know that ... thanks. (Although it would also be useful to have an *ordered* analogue of a dictionary to be able to ensure iteration in value order ...)

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  There are usually better ways...  :)

Comment: the ordered analogue of a dictionary/iteration in order, or the original symbol-referencing question?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `locals`:

```
s = 1
locals()['s']
```

EDIT:

Actually, `get` in R is more versatile - `get('as.list')` will give you back `as.list`. For class members, in Python, we can use `getattr` ([here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr)), and for built-in things like `len`, `getattr(__builtins__, 'len')` works.

Comment: This is much better than `eval()`.

Comment: @L3viathan: can you explain why?

Comment: `eval` will evaluate and execute any code you give it. In your case that might not make a difference, but in general it can be dangerous (with unverified/uncleaned input), it should almost always be avoided. `locals()` just returns a dictionary of local variables, which is what you want.

Comment: In case of regression `formula = y~ eval(s)` produces the desired result while  `formula = y~ locals()['s']` does not, any idea why?

Answer (score 6):

Use the `eval` function, which evaluates a string as an expression.

```
X = 10
r = "XVI"
v = eval(r[0])
```

Important note: `eval()` evaluates any code that can be used in an expression, not just variables. Do not use it directly in conjunction with user input, which could risk a security vulnerability.

Comment: I know this works, but it's not the "right" way to do it. `eval` is potentially dangerous and should almost always be avoided.

Comment: @L3viathan He said he wants a general solution. It doesn't necessarily mean he's taking user input. This is one solution.

Comment: A general solution to get the value of a "symbol". `locals()` will do that (or `globals()` for globals).

Comment: I understand/agree with the argument that `locals()` is better.  This was still a useful answer for me, so I'm upvoting it (but will probably accept the `locals()` answer).

Comment: @BenBolker, but if you ever need to accept user input like `"2*2+(4*3)"` or something, that'd be harder to do with `locals()`, but yeah, it's good for your roman numeral example. In the case of a math expression as user input, I'd maybe try validating with a regular expression before eval...