# How to pass dataframe to function using variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a few pandas dataframes `df_all_ticket_type`, `df_all_category`, `df_all_sub_category1` for which same function has to be called for some processing. The names of DFs are in a List.

```
list_df_names = ['df_all_ticket_type', 'df_all_category', 'df_all_sub_category1']
```

I want to call a function to clean these DFs using the List.

```
for df_name in list_df_names:
    clean_df(df_name)
```

`df_name` takes values of `df_all_ticket_type`, `df_all_category`, `df_all_sub_category1` for every iteration. I don't want to pass the value but the actual DF to the function. Is there a way I can achieve this?

Comment: Why do you have to use the names but not the date frames themselves?

Comment: delete the single quotes, `list_df_names = [df_all_ticket_type, df_all_category, df_all_sub_category1] `

Comment: yeah you can make a list of the dataframes themselves instead of their names

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `locals()` function (link to [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28245607/python-equivalent-of-get-in-r-use-string-to-retrieve-value-of-symbol))

```py
for df_name in list_df_names:
    clean_df(locals()[df_name])
```