# find the python synonym of get() in R language

Tags: python, get

In R language, I can get an object by combining its names like:

```
item_1 = "apple"

get(paste0('item_', '1'))
```

it will return "apple"

How can I do the same thing in Python?

In Python:

```
item_1 = 'apple'
```

I want to have a function such that:

```
function('item_' + '1')
```

will return 'apple'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28245607/10276092

Comment: From @M.Viking's link, try `locals()['item_' + '1']`.

Comment: Side comment: the use of  `get` in R is often associated with a not-best-practice way of working through identically-structured objects or working with poorly-framed functions. I rarely find its use truly required, typically better handled with other mechanisms. Just a thought, there isn't enough context for me to give any recommendation, and it might be off-base for your specific use-case.